# Haskell sum of one element of tuples

Tags: haskell

For example, I have a list of tuples (Int,String)

```
[ (10,"x"), (100,"y"), (-54,"z") ]
```

how do I calculate the sum of it (10+100-54) in Haskell as quick as possible ? 
I don't seem to get it with a fold function

Answer (score 8):

For this you could use `map` and the built in `sum`

```
 sum $ map fst [(10, "x"), (100, "y"), (-54, "z")]
```

where `fst` is the built in which if the equivalent of

```
 fst (x, y) = x
```

Answer (score 4):

`foldr (\(x,y) z -> x+z) 0` will do it in one pass.

Comment: You can also write that as `foldr ((+) . fst) 0`.

Comment: The compiler should get all these solutions down to one pass.